# Best way to back up a local install of TFS 2010 for a single developer

Tags: backup

I recently installed TFS 2010 on my laptop (Windows 7, 64-bit) for source control only (I don’t need reporting, Share Point, etc.) for some single-developer projects that I’m working on.  I’m pretty happy with the source control, but I’m trying to figure out the best strategy for backing it up in case of a drive failure, fire, theft, etc.

I tried using the Power Tools Backup Plan Wizard, but I kept getting a “Grant Backup Plan Permissions” error saying that the account did not have the required permissions to create backups on the backup path.  I suspect that the problem might be that I’m trying to back-up to an XP Home machine, and I think I need to have a machine that is on a domain.  (I realize this isn’t an ideal setup, but it’s what I’ve got.)

So I’ve got a few specific questions, but I’m also open to other suggestions.

Is there a way to use the Backup Plan Wizard to back up to an XP Home machine?

If I can’t make the Backup Plan Wizard work, what about just backing up the SQL Server databases that TFS uses?  The article here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070.aspx says that you need to use marked transactions to keep the data consistent, but I’m wondering if I could skip that and still make it work (since I’m the only developer and I could make sure that I’m not logged into TFS while the backup is running).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the Backup Plan Wizard working with XP Home, so I went ahead and manually set up the backups using the instructions given in the link above. It actually turned out to be pretty simple to do (a lot of steps, but they're all very easy). My first automatic backup ran overnight, and I was able to successfully restore the TFS databases.  I've also set things up so that the backup files (full, incremental, and transaction logs) are saved to my dropbox folder.